# Undefined Local Variable or Method 'food'

Tags: ruby, variables, undefined, local

Working in Ruby, I'm getting an error saying

```
'add': undefined local variable or method 'food' for #<FoodDB:...
```

This is the code I'm trying to run

```
require_relative 'FoodDB.rb'

class Manager
  def initialize
     food = FoodDB.new
     self.create_foodDB(food)
  end

  def create_foodDB(food)
    counter = 1
    word = []
    file = File.new("FoodDB.txt","r")   
    while (line = file.gets)
      food.addFood(line)
      counter = counter + 1
    end
    file.close
  end
end

manager = Manager.new

input_stream = $stdin
input_stream.each_line do |line|  
  line = line.chomp
  if line == "quit"
    input_stream.close
  end
end
```

This is FoodDB.rb's code

```
class FoodDB
  def initialize
    food = []
  end

  def addFood(str)
    food.push(str)
  end
end
```

I'm not sure what's the problem since it seems like I'm definitely calling the correct method from the FoodDB class. All help is appreciated, thank you!

Comment: could you please provide line of code with error?

Comment: Btw the convention in Ruby is to use `CamelCase` for classes and `snake_case` for constants, variables and method names.

Comment: A few other observations: 1. 'self.create_foodDB(food)' can be written 'create_foodDB(food)'; 2. in 'create_foodDB()', 'counter' and 'word' are not used; and 3. you could write 'if line.chomp == "quit"' and delete the previous line.

Comment: @CarySwoveland good observations although I suspect that the unused variables may be artifacts of the OP simplifying the code for his post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change `food` in the `FoodDB` class to an instance variable:

```
class FoodDB
  def initialize
    @food = []
  end

  def addFood(str)
    @food.push(str)
  end
end
```

An instance variable will be available throughout all methods of an instance, while the food variable you used was local to its lexical scope, i.e. only available within the `initialize` method.