# Ruby: trouble calling class instance from method

Tags: ruby, class, instance-variables

I'm obviously new to Ruby, and programming in general, and greatly appreciate any help.

Here is my code snippet:

```
class Player
    attr_accessor :name, :hp

    def initialize(name, hp)
        @name = name
        @hp = hp
    end

    def name
        @name
    end

    def hp
        @hp
    end
end

def prompt
    print "> "
end

prompt; pname = gets.chomp
player = Player.new(pname, rand(20..30))

puts "#{player.name} \:\: #{player.hp} HP"

def test
    puts "#{player.name} \:\: #{player.hp} HP - IN METHOD"
end

test
```

When run, here are the results:

$ ruby wtf.rb

```
> Test Name

Test Name :: 20 HP

wtf.rb:24:in `test': undefined local variable or method `player' for main:Object (NameError) from wtf.rb:27:in `<main>'
```

Why does my call work in the first instance, but not the second?  Is it because it is now looking for a new "player" variable within the "test" method?  If so, how do I go about calling the one from the class instance created earlier?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def test
  puts "#{player.name} \:\: #{player.hp} HP - IN METHOD"
end
```

You forgot to pass `player` into the method:

```
def test(player)
  puts "#{player.name} \:\: #{player.hp} HP - IN METHOD"
end

test(player) # => player = Player.new(pname, rand(20..30)) :: 22 HP - IN METHOD
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this makes perfect sense.

Answer (score 1):

`player` is defined as a local variable outside the scope of the method `test`,

change references of  `player` to `@player`, making it an instance variable

Here is a quick [reference](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Ruby_Variable_Scope) on scope and variables, and also a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19488676/undefined-local-variable-or-method-food)

As a side note you shouldn't use `test` as a method name, because it is already defined on [Kernel](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Kernel.html#method-i-test)

```
irb(main):001:0> method(:test)
=> #<Method: Object(Kernel)#test>
```

Comment: Thank you for the reference and the note about using test as a method name!

Answer (score 0):

Ruby doesn't have lexical scope for methods like Javascript for functions, so this (ruby):

```
player = Player.new(pname, rand(20..30))
def test
    # error: undefined variable or method 'player', 
    # this happens because player was defined
    # in an unrelated scope outside this method
    puts "#{player.name} \:\: #{player.hp} HP - IN METHOD"
end
test
```

Is **NOT** equivalent to this (javascript)

```
var player = new Player(pname, ...);
var test = function() {
    # works as expected, player is available because it was defined
    # in the parent scope
    console.log(player.name + "\:\:" + player.hp + " HP - IN METHOD");
};
test();
```

If you want something similar to lexical scope on ruby, maybe you should use lambda

```
player = Player.new(pname, rand(20..30))
test = lambda do
    # works as expected, this block scope inherits from parent scope where the block
    # was created, so, it can access player local variable
    puts "#{player.name} \:\: #{player.hp} HP - IN METHOD"
end
test.call
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment; being new to programming, I don't understand your response but it's given me something new to research.